# Postgis load raster to DB running on AWS RDS with raster2pgsql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-raster, raster2pgsql

I want to perform very common task:

1. I have Postgresql + Postgis running on Amazon Web Service cloud, using RDS service.
2. I have there some vector layers and can execute SQL (Postgis) commands via connection using Pgadmin3 SQL console. So I know for sure that Postgis is installed OK.
3. Also I can execute psql console with `SELECT PostGIS_Version();` running OK.

The next is to execute something like `raster2pgsql -G;` in order to test that the raster2pgsql tool installed. The problem is it doesn't.

Basically When one using Potsgresql on AWS RDS the Postgis is pre-installed. And if so, tools like "raster2pgsql" should be automatically also be installed.

1. How now I can install this tool on such remote DB? I have access to psql and that's it.
2. My task is to load raster data (topo) in the way I can leveraged Postgis spatial queries. What are my other alternatives to load into Postgis DB DTED files?